# Bootstrap 3.3.7 with codeigniter

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am trying to use bootstrap navigator bar but it doesn't work.
I have created a template folder which contain the CSS of the front page in the view.
My code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <title> TTS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("asset/css/bootstrap.css"); ?>" />

        <style type="text/css"> 
            #img{
                display:block;
                position:relative;
                left:0px;
                float:left;
                margin-left:10px;
            }
            #img2{
                display:block;
                position:relative;
                right:0px;
                float:right;
                margin-right:10px;
            }
            #img3{
                display:block;
                position:relative;
                left:0px;
                float:left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("asset/js/jquery.js"); ?>"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("asset/js/bootstrap.js"); ?>"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the php file for the view is:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TTS</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

the controller is:

```
    <?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class firstpage extends CI_Controller {
        public function __construct() {     
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper('url');
            $this->load->helper('html');
            $this->load->helper('form');
        }

        public function index(){
            $this->load->view('templates/front_template/front');
            $this->load->view('front_page/firstpage');
        }
    } ?>
```

Can I get help in `this.searched` everywhere didn't get the right answer.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'it doesn't work'. Do you het any error message? Is the display broken?

Comment: aside - change your opening html to: <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
  <head> see this for a basic template: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41610470/codeigniter-cors-policy-no-access-control-allow-origin-error-how-to-resolve

Answer (score 1):

Check if it has ip in url in your firefox firebug or developer tools   if so make sure you have set your base_url it is required

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/projectname/';
```

And your missing the `type="text/css"`

And no need to close controllers with ?>

Comment: i have removed <?php?> form the  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("asset/css/bootstrap.css"); ?>" /> .to havea normal html and it works.same to the jquery script have removed <?php?>  <link rel="stylesheet" href="asset/css/bootstrap.css" />     <script type="text/javascript" src="asset/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="asset/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would help but try removing the `echo` from the this line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("asset/css/bootstrap.css"); ?>" />
```

it should be like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php base_url("asset/css/bootstrap.css"); ?>" />
```