# Codeigniter cors policy error how to resolve?

Tags: php, codeigniter

> **Error:**
>
> CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource.

Anyone can Please Help me why this error is displaying and How can I resolve this error? You can Check error on http://kakaproperty.com.

I tried solution but it not working. so I asked Question.

Comment: You should post more context of your code, btw you can check this solution, it should work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41610470/codeigniter-cors-policy-no-access-control-allow-origin-error-how-to-resolve#41610512

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error How to resolve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41610470/codeigniter-cors-policy-no-access-control-allow-origin-error-how-to-resolve)

Comment: set this line in `.htaccess` file `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` and make your Rewrite mode on also in .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You have to solve the problem by adding this lines directly in your controller

```
Header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); //for allow any domain, insecure
Header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *'); //for allow any headers, insecure
Header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE'); //method allowed
```